# Adding a row to already Dimensionalized Array

Tags: excel, vba

In the first part of my sub I put some formulas into a row using lastrow + 1.

```
.Range("B" & lastrow + 1 & ":" & "I" & lastrow + 1).Value = _
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C7:J7").Value
```

How I declare last row:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = FindLastRow("Sheet Name")
```

Later on in my code in the same sub, I do an average of this column, but now lastrow has remained the same. But I need to redo the lastrow because I've added a row to this dataset. How can I redo this?

Comment: Just call whatever sets `lastrow` again - typically something like `lastrow = Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: `lastrow = lastrow +1` should be all you need?

Comment: Can I just recall the variable? Added code to the question for clarity.

Comment: @TimWilliams I after I do my row data, then I redo lastrow? I think last row needs to be recalled in my situation.

Comment: Yes just recall that `FindLastRow()` function

Comment: Because you have a function to find the last row (I don't know why but anyway) you can ommit the Lastrow variable and just have `.Range("B" & FindLastRow("Sheet Name")
+ 1 & ":" & "I" & FindLastRow("Sheet Name")
+ 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C7:J7").Value` yes it calls it twice but I hardly think it will impact the time or the processor drastically.

Answer (score 0):

For this example i use Sheet1 - Column A.Before you calculate the average, recalculate the the last row. See below the example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LR As Long
    Dim Avg As Double

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Avg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(.Range("A1:A" & LR))

    End With



End Sub
```